# Hitboxes in Java game without Rectangles

Tags: java, collision

I am new to making games in Java but I made some games using the paintComponent method, however I felt like I was missing something. So I wanted to see different options of rendering graphics etc. I therefore googled around and I just got stuck on painting individual pixels. I thought that was really cool. However, I have some issues with it.

The main issue is that the collision system isn't working great. In my case I right now use an image of a block as a player. This block sometimes get overlapped by the level image.

*Here is an image of the issue:*

[image]

As you can see the level image overlaps the player image in the corner. I read some posts about fixing it, they mentioned that I should set the position of the block to the position right before colliding. However this made it even worse as the player just teleported back and forth.

I thought that making a GIF of  the issue wouldn't hurt, so here you go!

[image]

It seems to me that the corners aren't correctly set?

Here is the code:

**The Render method in GameManager (Handles the collision code)**:

```
    @Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Renderer renderer) {

    for(GameObject obj : list) {    //Draw objects
        obj.setGoRight(true);
        obj.setGoLeft(true);
        obj.setGoUp(true);
        obj.setGoDown(true);
        obj.render(gc, renderer);


        //Collision     

        for(int y = 2; y < obj.getHeight() - 2; y++) {


//TODO CORNERS DON'T HAVE COLLISION, FIX 

            if(collision[(obj.getxCord()) + ((obj.getyCord() + y) * gc.getWidth())] ) { //GLITCHES INTO BLOCK

                    obj.setxCord(obj.getxCord());
                    obj.setGoLeft(false);       //MOVEMENT LEFT



                }


            if(collision[obj.getxCord() + obj.getWidth() + ((obj.getyCord() + y) * gc.getWidth())] ) {
                //MOVEMENT RIGHT
                obj.setxCord(obj.getxCord());
                obj.setGoRight(false);

            }

        }




        for(int x = 3; x < obj.getWidth() - 3; x++) {   //SKJUTER SÅ DE INTE SKANNAR KANTERNA, DVS SÅ ATT X OCH Y AXELN HAR SAMMA HITBOX

        if(collision[(obj.getxCord() + x) + ((obj.getyCord() + obj.getHeight()) * gc.getWidth())] ) {

            //MOVEMENT DOWN
            obj.setyCord(obj.getyCord());
            obj.setGoDown(false);

        }
        if(collision[(obj.getxCord() + x) + (obj.getyCord()  * gc.getWidth())] ) {

            //MOVEMENT UP
            obj.setGoUp(false);
            obj.setyCord(obj.getyCord());

        }

      }


    }






    renderer.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0);
}
```

**The Player class**

```
public class Player extends GameObject{
private Image image;
private int speed = 2;
String imagePath = "/picture.png";


public Player() {
    this.xCord = 160;
    this.yCord = 120;
    image = new Image(imagePath);
    tag = "player";
    this.width = image.getWidth();
    this.height = image.getHeight();

    this.hitBox = new Rectangle(this.xCord,this.yCord,this.width,this.height);


}
@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, float updatetime) {

    if(goLeft) {

        if(gc.getInput().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {

            this.xCord -= speed;
        }

    }
    if(goRight ) {

        if(gc.getInput().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {

            xCord += speed;

        }

    }
    if(goUp) {

         if(gc.getInput().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {

                yCord -= speed;
            }

    }
    if(goDown) {

         if(gc.getInput().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {

                yCord += speed;
                System.out.println(yCord);
            }

    }




     if(gc.getInput().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_K)) {

        this.setDead(true);
    }
     this.setHitBox(hitBox);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Renderer renderer) {
    renderer.drawImage(image,xCord,yCord);  

}
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
} 

}
```

**The Level loading method in GameManager**:

```
    public void loadLevel(String levelPath) {

    backgroundImg= new Image(levelPath);

    levelWidth = backgroundImg.getWidth();
    levelHeight = backgroundImg.getHeight();

    collision = new boolean[levelHeight * levelWidth];
    for(int y = 0; y < levelHeight; y++) {

        for(int x = 0; x < levelWidth; x++) {

            if(backgroundImg.getPixels()[x + (y * levelWidth)] == new Color(0,0,0).getRGB()) {  

                collision[x + (y * levelWidth)] = true;
                if(collision[x+(y * levelWidth)]) {

                    backgroundImg.getPixels()[x + (y * levelWidth)] = 56;
                }

            }
            else collision[x + (y * levelWidth)] = false;
        }
    }

}






}
```

**So what am I trying to do?**

When the player collides with any of the pixels that I set as colliding pixels in the loadLevel() method earlier, I want him to stop moving. A simple idea but it turned out difficult.

I have the two for loops in the collision part of render() to change the hitbox.

If I don't use these loops I can't move up or down when I hit a wall on my left or right side. And if I hit the roof I can't move left and right etc.

The for loops therefore change where the player's hitbox is places. This makes the player's corner seem like it doesn't exist. If I paint the image right in my head it should look like:

[image]

Any tips regarding how I might change the code to solve the issue are appreciated! I looked at many posts regarding this before, but they used Rectangles which isn't really the same as checking the player x and y value with individual pixels?

People might also ask why I use a pixel system. Which is a fair question. My only answer is that I want to draw a level in paint then import that image instead of coding where things shall be placed? I just found that this might be a smarter solution! So I make a pixelart map, then I make a separate image where I put black pixels where collision blocks are etc. I hope you get my point!

I do however think this system is a bit complicated, but I didn't find a good way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to reduce the complexity of this question down a bit. Is the issue the rounded surface not colliding with the corner of the box? Is the issue you detect the collision, but don't know what to do about it?

Comment: @matt The issue is that the player corners and sometimes sides get covered up by the level object as can be seen on the images above. I dont really now how to solve the issue.. Sorry for a complex question. I just wanted to give as much information as possible!

Comment: One thing that would make the problem more obvious is to draw the background first, then draw the player.  A reason people use rectangles for collision detection is that the Java Rectangle class has an intersects method already coded.  What you need to do is code your own intersects method where you check whether your player intersects any objects.  It helps a lot if you have a logical model of your game, from which the physical pixels are drawn.  Perhaps, you'll get more help at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @GilbertLeBlanc . I used Rectangles in my last game. But I because I paint the picture in a different way than the paintComponent do, I struggled to install them on the character. And I couldn't figure out how I to set rectangles on a drawn image! I have some issues I'll have to fight with. I'll see if they have a solution to the issue

Comment: @DubstepZedd The way I see it, when you move you should check if you can move there. The way you have posed the question you have two issues. 1. Collision detection. 2. Drawing your player. You haven't really separated the two. If you assume that you draw the player correctly, then you need to make sure the collision is being detected.

Comment: The player is being draw correct. I have x and y cords for the player. I have a speed that gets added or subtracted with the coords depending on which direction of course.

Comment: You mean that I should check if pixel + 1 is a collision pixel? Why? what should I do if that returns true? I can't stop right then because then I will be 1 pixel away from the collision pixel right? @matt

Comment: I changed so the player is being drawn after the map btw, so thats fixed

Comment: Here is one way to think of a collision. You want to move, you check if you can move there. You don't check pixel+1. You say player + vel, check for collision if there is a collision, change the velocity so you don't collide.

Comment: Another thing you can do, I think this sits with your 1px border idea. You move and you check your 1px region. If there is a collision, then you cannot move in a direction. You player should *not* get moved away, you just need to make a constraint that the player cannot move in the direction of the pixel that has the collision.

Comment: I see. That would be easier if I didn't have a boolean array. The "collision" array basically says if the pixel at (x+y*screenWidth) is a collision pixel. In this case I would have to do: collision[((playerx + speed) + (playery * screenWidth))] ? I tried that earlier but it didn't really work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210602/discussion-between-matt-and-dubstepzedd).

Comment: That 1px thing would only work for speed 2 I think.. Because if speed is 3 it has to check x + 1 and x + 2 before moving? I am doing this thought in my head rn so It might be faulty

Comment: So basically, it works like this. The speed of the player can currently only be 2, I haven't figured that out. The tiles have to be even numbers and so needs the size of the player. If the player's size is odd, the tiles need to be odd as well. That part makes sense.

The speed however should be able to adjust to even numbers as well but that doesn't work. This isn't really an answer, I am more informing the rest of the people that enters this post what caused the issue. I didn't want tiles from the first place in this game. However, I guess that is the only option when doing pixel by pixel.